# Haskell exceptions what mask/restore is particulary doing

Tags: exception, haskell

I'm trying to understand how masking exceptions works in general case on a simple sample code, here is the `bracket` fn in library sources:

```hs
    bracket before after thing =
      mask $ \restore -> do
        a <- before
        r <- restore (thing a) `onException` after a
        _ <- after a
        return r
```

Here is my "bracket" version without `mask`

```hs
    myBracket before after thing = do
      a <- before
      r <- thing a `onException` after a
      _ <- after a
      pure r
```

I'm testing it with this simple code like this:

```hs
   tid <- forkIO $ bracket acquire release work
   treadDelay some
   throwTo tid MyException
```

I throw custom exceptions at different moments: when `acquire`, `work`, and `release` are executed, and for both `bracket` and `myBracket` I get the same results.

So my question is how do I modify my sample/testing code so that the role of mask/restore in exception handling is visible/obvious?

Comment: My guess is that the masking should prevent async exceptions like your `throwTo` to fall in the middle of `before` or `after`. You wrote you tried to interrupt that, but you didn't say how. Perhaps you can make `acquire` print something, wait 1 second, and repeat that 10-ish times so you can spot it being interrupted.

Comment: Without `mask`, if an asynchronous exception happens between `before` and `thing`, or between `thing` and `after`, `after` won't be called and the bracketed resource won't be released. This is a good explanation: https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/parallel-and-concurrent/9781449335939/ch09.html

Comment: @danidiaz To test this, I added `threadDelay 10000000` between the `before` and `thing` lines. But `release` does not run whether I call `mask` or not! So `mask` doesn't appear to help with the race you describe. What's up with that?

Comment: @DanielWagner I wrote an answer that explains that behavior.

Comment: The problem in my samples is that threadDelay is interruptible action that is not masked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting from ["Parallel and Concurrent Programming in Haskell"](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/parallel-and-concurrent/9781449335939/ch09.html):

> a small number of operations, including takeMVar, are designated as interruptible. Interruptible operations may receive asynchronous exceptions even inside mask.

> What justifies this choice? Think of mask as *switching to polling mode for asynchronous exceptions*. Inside a mask, asynchronous exceptions are no longer asynchronous, but they can still be raised by certain operations. In other words, asynchronous exceptions become synchronous inside mask.

In your `mask`-using bracket, the `before` and `after` actions might still throw an asynchronous exception if they happen to use interruptible operations like `takeMVar`, `threadDelay`, or `hClose`. Even inside `mask`! In general, `IO` operations that might make the user wait for long periods of time tend to be interruptible.

What `mask` ensures is that asynchronous exceptions won't happen in the interstices between `IO` actions, or for `IO` actions that can't cause long waits. This make asynchronous exceptions much more manageable. You can, for example, handle them with a `try`, without fearing that the `try` itself might get interrupted.<sup>1</sup>

In your version of `bracket` without `mask`, an asynchronous exception might crop up between the execution of `before` and `thing`, or between the execution of `thing` and `after`. In both cases, `after` won't get executed and the bracketed resource will remain unreleased.

<sup>1</sup><sub>That said, any async exception that is caught should eventually be re-thrown.</sub>

---

Note that, according to the above, if you pass something like `threadDelay 10000000` as `before`, it  might totally throw an asynchronous exception, even inside `mask`! It's your responsability to pass `before` actions (that is, allocation actions) that don't leave unreleased resources hanging when interrupted.

Functions like [`openFile`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/System-IO.html#v:openFile) do the right thing in those cases, and this, plus the knowledge that `bracket` is properly masked, means the user doesn't have to worry.

---

By the way: we said that [`hClose`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/GHC-IO-Handle.html#v:hClose) is interruptible. Should be worried about interrupted `bracket`s leaving unclosed handles? No, because the contract for `hClose` says:

> hClose is an interruptible operation in the sense described in Control.Exception. If hClose is interrupted by an asynchronous exception in the process of flushing its buffers, then the I/O device (e.g., file) will be closed anyway.

So, `hClose` will close the handle even if interrupted.

---

This piece of code uses [`uninterruptibleMask_`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/GHC-IO.html#v:uninterruptibleMask_) (a function which should be used with great care due to its propensity to make programs unresponsive) to create an un-interruptible `threadDelay` which is passed to `bracket`.

The masked version of `bracket` will print `"after"`. The mask-less version won't.

This is because, without `mask`, the exception thrown to the thread will surface *immediately* after `before` finishes, without giving time to install the `onException` handler which ensures cleanup.

In contrast, for the masked version of `bracket`, the exception doesn't surface until we call the `restore` callback. But at that point the `onException` handler has already been installed.

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    tid <- forkIO $
        bracket 
        -- myBracket 
            (uninterruptibleMask_ $ threadDelay 9000000) 
            (\_ -> hPutStrLn stderr "after")
            (\_ -> threadDelay 1000000) 
    threadDelay 2000000
    -- throwTo blocks until "before" finishes because the uninterruptible mask
    throwTo tid (userError "boo") 
    threadDelay 1000000
    pure ()
```

Comment: Thanks for the elaboration! This answers my question exactly, so I used an interruptible action (treadDelay) for the test.

Comment: @WHITECOLOR Another thing you could try to test the two versions of `bracket` is to pass something like `uninterruptibleMask_ (threadDelay 9000000)` as `before` https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/GHC-IO.html#v:uninterruptibleMask_ and something like `\_ -> putStrLn "after"` as after. Then, throw an asynchronous exception to the bracket after 5 seconds. The uninterruptible mask will delay the exception until after `before` completes. The mask-less version of `bracket` will not run `after`, but the masked version should.

Answer (score 3):

If the exception gets thrown during `acquire`, then we may never `release` if there's no masking. Here's a crisp demonstration:

```
big = 100000000
acquire n = putStrLn "acquire start" >> evaluate (last [0..n]) >> putStrLn "acquire stop"
release _ = putStrLn "release"
work _ = putStrLn "work"

main = do
  tid <- forkIO $ myBracket (acquire (2*big)) release work
  evaluate (last [0..big])
  throwTo tid MyException
  threadDelay 1000000 -- so prints don't overlap

  tid <- forkIO $ bracket (acquire (2*big)) release work
  evaluate (last [0..big])
  throwTo tid MyException
  threadDelay 1000000 -- so the program doesn't exit until prints are done
```

When run, we can see that `release` only prints the second time, for `bracket`:

```
% ghc test && ./test
Loaded package environment from /home/dmwit/.ghc/x86_64-linux-8.10.4/environments/default
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( test.hs, test.o )
Linking test ...
acquire start
test: MyException
acquire start
acquire stop
release
test: MyException
```

Comment: Thanks very much for, the answer, it gives a useful hints and working sample. Though it doesn't answer why my test code was not working, so I marked as a solution another one that does.